# AJAX displaying html page in html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to AJAX and Jquery, What I am trying to do is display a second HTML file in the body of my first one when a button is clicked. I had no luck so far, nothing happens when the button is clicked. All of the html files are in the same directory as my index.html. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

this is the navigation in my website and my function invoking AJAX  named callPage

```
<div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li> <a onclick="callPage('login.html')">Login</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="callPage('register.html')">Register</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="callPage('guide.html')">Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function callPage(pageRefInput){
        $.ajax({
            url:pageRefInput,
            type: "GET",
            dataType:'text/html',

            success:function(response){
                console.log('ok',response);
                $('.content').html(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('err',error);
            },
            complete:function(xhr,status){
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are your URL is a file URL ?

Comment: yes they are. Located in the same directory as all of my other website related files @Kornflexx

Comment: Do you know the purpose of `$(document).ready`? Do you know what scope the functions called in attribute event handlers have to be in?

Comment: @Musa Clearly not, sorry.

Comment: Another mistake is: **dataType:'text/html',**. According to [ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the **dataType** can be: "xml" or "html" or... Hence, change your dateType to:  **dataType:'html',**

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks for the input, I changed it. Still cant make it work though

Comment: can you try: **$('.content').load('your url');**

Comment: you say "website" and that your URL's are "file URL" ... let me clarify, by *file URL* I think the question was, is the page loaded using `file:///` protocol or `http(s)://` - if the former, then, a) it's hardly a **web** site, and b) some browsers (i.e. Chrome) won't let you do AJAX over `file:///` protocol unless you pass in a command line argument to enable it. Easiest fix, if you want to write a **web** site, then use a **web** protocol. And finally, browsers have a ***developer** tools console* - check for any "messages" there

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your function outside from `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

```js
function callPage(pageRefInput) {
  console.log(pageRefInput)
  /*$.ajax({
    url: pageRefInput,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'text/html',

    success: function(response) {
      console.log('ok', response);
      $('.content').html(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('err', error);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
      console.log('complete');
    }
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar-left">
  <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li> <a onclick="callPage('login.html')">Login</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="callPage('register.html')">Register</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="callPage('guide.html')">Guide</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or you can bind the event `click` using `addEventListener` and store the URL into a `data-attribute`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
    a.addEventListener('click', callPage);
  });
});

function callPage(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.dataset.url;
  console.log(url);

  /*$.ajax({
    url: pageRefInput,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'text/html',

    success: function(response) {
      console.log('ok', response);
      $('.content').html(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('err', error);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
      console.log('complete');
    }
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar-left">
  <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li> <a data-url='login.html'>Login</a></li>
    <li><a data-url='register.html'>Register</a></li>
    <li><a data-url='guide.html'>Guide</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed my code with data-urls and included   window.alert(url); just to see if it will pop-up with the url and it does, but the html file in the url is still not displayed in the html body